# Pubnub presence limit to 20

Tags: javascript, python, pubnub

I'm implementing presence with pubnub, and I'm encountering a problem, I create a method to get the presence in python, and its working properly, when I connect one to 20 users simultaniously, but once I created more, I didn't get the proper response of the joins users.. I created a simple js script to subscribe users..

```
var pubnub =[];
  for(i=0; i<=100;i++) {
     pubnub[i] = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key: "subkey",
        uuid: "user"+i
     });
   }
```

After the first 20 I just get the occupancy in the response of the presence method, instead of the usual, join or leave action with the corresponding uuid.

Does it have a limitation, or perhaps, pubnub know that I'm opening them from the same ip and its blocking subscriptions somehow? I would like to know how it is the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cri_sys, this is a server-side optimization to be sure we don't flood you with data when there is too much presence data coming over the line.

Contact us at support@pubnub.com, and we can adjust it to < 20 behavior for you, or go into more detail on why you may want the alternative behavior when > 20.

geremy

Comment: The thing is that i should in realtime change the status of the users in my system, i could get them all with here_now but if i just get them all i will have to update everyuser online.
But instead i would like to get just the user that changed the status, online offline, as the presence does.
Or maybe theres a way that presence will send me an array of status changes, in the last minnute for instance, so i could update just the user that have really changed.

any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, its a server-side optimization that we're happy to adjust for you. Please contact us at support@pubnub.com and we'll be sure to get you configured as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The Presence Announce Max property is now exposed as a property in the Presence add-on panel in your account portal. You can set the value as high as 100. If you want it set higher, you need to contact support@pubnub.com.